# Complex Numbers Proof

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I have the statement, $|1 -zw^*|^2 - |z-w|^2 = (1 - |z|^2)(1-|w|)^2)$

Expanding $|1 -zw^*|^2$ gives me:
$1 - z^*w -zw^* - |z|^2$

Expanding $|z-w|^2$ gives:
$|z|^2 - zw^* - z^*w + |w|^2$

Subtracting both equations gives me:
$1 - 2|z|^2 - |w|^2$

This what the right hand side expands to:
$1 - |w|^2 - |z|^2 -|w|^2$

Now I am stuck ... Did I mess up my expansions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340317/help-with-tough-proof-involve-complex-numbers

Comment: Typo in your second line. $|z|^2$ should be $|z|^2|w|^2$. Things should work out after that.

Comment: I just realized that my expansion failed. It does in fact work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|1-zw^*|^2=(1-zw^*)\cdot(1-z^*w)=1-z^*w-zw^*+zw^*\cdot z^*w=1-z^*w-zw^*+|z|^2\cdot|w|^2$$

and similarly

$$|z-w|^2=(z-w)\cdot(z^*-w^*)=|z|^2-zw^*-z^*w+|w|^2$$

then

$|1-zw^*|^2-|z-w|^2=1+|z|^2\cdot|w|^2-|z|^2-|w|^2=(1-|z|^2)\cdot(1-|w|^2)$

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy,w=a+ib$

$\implies w*=a-ib, zw*=(x+iy)(a-ib)=(xa+yb)+i(ya-xb)$

and $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},|w|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$$|1 -zw^*|^2 - |z-w|^2 = |1-xa-yb+i(xb-ya)|^2-|x-a+i(y-b)|^2$$

$$=(1-xa-yb)^2+(xb-ya)^2-\{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2\}$$

$$=1+x^2a^2+y^2b^2+2abxy-2ax-2by+x^2b^2+y^2a^2-2abxy-(x^2+a^2-2ax+y^2+b^2-2by)$$

$$=1-x^2-y^2-a^2(-x^2-y^2+1)-b^2(-y^2-x^2-1)$$

$$=(1-x^2-y^2)(1-a^2-b^2)$$